# How to fix string declaration error in scope

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, ipc, msgrcv

I'm trying to run an interprocess communication program but it says string is not declared in the scope as is and when I add #inlcude  I get an error that says:

```
receiver.cpp:25:35: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
     string temp = to_string(argv[0]);
                             ~~~~~~^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52:0,
                 from receiver.cpp:14:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:6419:3: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::string std::__cxx11::to_string(unsigned int) <near match>
   to_string(unsigned __val)
   ^~~~~~~~~
receiver.cpp:27:26: error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int atoi(const char*)’
     int msgid = atoi(temp) //Converts message id from string to integer
                          ^
receiver.cpp:45:32: error: ‘some_data’ was not declared in this scope
     if (msgrcv(msgid, (void *)&some_data, BUFSIZ, msg_to_receive, 0) == -1) { //revieces message from message queue
                                ^~~~~~~~~
receiver.cpp:49:29: error: ‘some_data’ was not declared in this scope
     printf("You wrote: %s", some_data.some_text);
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.H>
#include <cstring.h>
#include <unist.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#inlcude <string>

using namespace std;

struct my_msg_st{
long int my_msg_type;
char some_text[BUFSIZ];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[0]){
int running =1;
string temp = to_string(argv[0]);
int msgid = atoi(temp);
struct my_msg_st some_data;
long int msg_to_receive = 0;

....

if (strncmp(some_data.some_text, "end", 3) == 0){
    running =0;
}

...
exit(0);
}
```

expecting for the code to print out the message sent from the sender file

Comment: BTW, objects of `std::string` can be compared using the `==` operator.  You should convert everything to `std::string` so you don't mix things up.

Comment: In your *posted* code, where do you read from a file?

Comment: You don't need to use `struct` when declaring parameters or variables; this is C++, not C.

Comment: You don't need `to_string` to convert from `char*` (that overload doesn't even exist). And `atoi` takes a `const char*`, not a std::string`.

Comment: To fix the first issue, `argv[0]` is already a string so you don't need to use `to_string`.  Look up the definitions of `to_string` and `std::string constuctor` in your favorite C++ reference

Comment: I believe `to_string` is part of C++11, but it only applies to numerical types. Also see [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some fixes for your issues:
`string temp = to_string(argv[0]);`
1. [`to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) converts numbers to string.  the `argv[0]` is a C-style string, not a number.
2. The `std::string` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) already has a version to convert from `char *` to `std::string`.

`atoi(temp)`
1. The [`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) function takes a parameter of type `char *` not `std::string`.  You'll need to use `atoi(temp.c_str())` or *prefer* `std::ostringstream`.

Please review the differences between `char` arrays (a.k.a. C-Style strings) and the `std::string` type.  Prefer to use `std::string`, especially in structures.

Carefully read the library function descriptions before using them.

See also `std::ostringstream`.  Since this is C++, prefer to use C++ I/O such as `std::cout` and `operator <<`.